# hWnd PostMessage simulation of a left keypress doesn't work

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage, hwnd

I'm trying to make a program that will simulate a `LEFT` keypress to a window.

I'm using this:

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(0x25), new IntPtr(0));
```

and this:

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(0x25), new IntPtr(0));
```

But the results of these two lines of code aren't identical to the result of normally pressing `LEFT` on the window...

Normally pressing `LEFT`(WORKS):

```
P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_LEFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:4B fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_LEFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode:4B fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

`PostMessage`ing a `LEFT` keypress (DOESN'T WORK):

```
P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_LEFT cRepeat:0 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_LEFT cRepeat:0 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
```

Why is that? Is it because of the `cRepeat`, `ScanCode`, `fExtended`, `fRepeat` and `fUp` that aren't the same? if so how do I set them correctly?

Comment: Same answer, as always: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Answer (score 0):

First, for the `cRepeat`..., according to the [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) and [`WM_KEYUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup)
It is in different bits of `lParam`.
To set them:

```
//WM_KEYDOWN
UINT scan = 0x1 | 0x4b << 16 | 0x1 << 24 | 0x0 << 30 | 0x0 << 31;
//WM_KEYUP
scan = 0x1 | 0x4b << 16 | 0x1 << 24 | 0x1 << 30 | 0x1 << 31;
```

Then, as metioned in [Raymond's article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513), using `PostMessage` to simulate keyboard input is unreliable.
Instead, you could use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) method. Of course you can use [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netframework-4.8) wrapped in forms.

Before that you need to get the keyboard focus.

```
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
```

Comment: [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083). I find it a fair bit unsettling to see users with an *"MSFT"* tag in their user names consistently publish wrong or dangerously incomplete answers. Using the accept ratio is likely the wrong metric if the goal is quality.